# Bash - when using Double Square brackets and when single square brackets

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, ksh

Please follow the following example (please notice that **STRING** is null)

Get Error

```
 [root@linux /tmp]# STRING=
 [root@linux /tmp]#  [ $STRING = dog ] && echo "yes its a dog"
 bash: [: =: unary operator expected
```

Syntax without Error

```
 [root@linux /tmp]# STRING=
 [root@linux /tmp]# [[ $STRING = dog ]] && echo "yes its a dog"
 [root@linux /tmp]# [[ $STRING != dog ]] && echo "yes its a dog"
 yes its a dog
```

Why when I am using Single Square brackets I get - **unary operator expected** ?

But in case of Double Square brackets the syntax give good results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike `[[ ]]`, single square brackets are subject to word splitting like normal commands. Think of it similarly as passing arguments to `test` builtin. `[[ ]]` are special and variables within it are not split with IFS. This is why it's preferable to use `[[ ]]` since it's more efficient and safer.

This one is just one of the things you can't do with `[`. With `[` you'd play around with `{ }` and `( )` to make it work. Note that `( )` summons a subshell and `{ }` would always need a semicolon in the end which is ugly. However you can do it safely with `[[ ]]`:

```
[[ a != b && c != d && ( something || something ) ]]
```

By the way to fix your problem you have to place the variable in double-quotes to prevent splitting:

```
[ "$STRING" = dog ]
```

With `[[` it's not needed.

Sere Word Splitting: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html

**Add:**

It seems like `$STRING` there was actually skipped as an argument for being empty instead of being split. Similarly the concept of it being interpreted as a normal command would apply and applying double quotes would fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Because `[[` is special. `[` needs to retain [Bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) compatibility, *including its limitations*. Since `[[` is a construct introduced separately in bash, it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to search on, but this is very frequently asked.  Try googling for "bash square brackets" and you will see lots of discussions on this topic, mostly on SO:

https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+square+brackets

https://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29

The short answer is to always use [[ unless you know otherwise...